# How d I use SelectedItemBinding if it's a string (when combobox is bound to a list of Colour)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

If my combobox data column is bound like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Chroma Colour" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ChromaColour}">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DefaultColours, ElementName=MyRoomFinish2}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DefaultColours, ElementName=MyRoomFinish2}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Where Colour is defined as:

```
  public class Colour
{
    string Name;
    int m_red = 0;
    int m_green = 0;
    int m_blue = 0;
    List<string> m_materials = null;


    public Colour(string name, int r, int g, int b, List<string> materials) 
    {
        Name = name;

        m_red = r;
        m_green = g;
        m_blue = b;

        m_materials = materials;
    }
    public Colour(string name, string r, string g, string b, List<string> materials)
    {
        Name = name;

        m_red = m_green = m_blue = 0;
        m_materials = materials;

        try
        {
            m_red = Int32.Parse(r);
            m_green = Int32.Parse(g);
            m_blue = Int32.Parse(b);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_red + "," + m_green + "," + m_blue;
    }
}
```

Where DefaultColours is a property on a parent class that returns a list of Colour objects that have their ToString() overridden to output the RGB values like "255,255,255" say.

The combobox itself as you can see above is bound using SelectedItemBinding but points to a property that returns a string of the same RGB format "255,255,255".

So simply put, the selectedvaluebinding is pointing a different class type (string) than to the list that the combobox is bound to (Colour object).

When the combobox first appears it always shows a blank field in the colour column. But if I change the combobox to be bound to a list of strings instead, it works.

How can I get the initial value in the Combobox to show correctly the bound value but still keeping it bound to a list of Colour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SelectedItem` doesn't directly relate to the list of `Colour`s, you'll need to use a `ValueConverter` to translate a `string` into a `Colour` that exists in your `ObservableCollection<Colour>` list to which the `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` is bound to.

Here is a link to a tutorial that explains ValueConverters
http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Inside your class that implements `IValueConverter`, you'll need to convert the `string` that your `SelectedItem` is bound to into a `Colour` object that exists in your `ObservableCollection<Colour>` list.

However, is there a reason that your `SelectedItem` is bound to a string?  Why not make your `SelectedItem` a `Colour` object.  This way, there is no conversion necessary.

Comment: Ma name's Wyatt EARP!! You make a good point, it's just that I would need to traverse the colours list and direct the property to point at it. However I think what you suggest is probably a better idea. Thanks for your reply much appreciated.